# Changing colour typeface for outline-minor-mode-highlight

Tags: outline, face-attributes

I am using outline-minor-mode-highlight but want to set different colours to the typeface according to same contrast levels not provided by the default settings of outline-minor-mode.  What can I do?

Comment: Please don't post the same question in emacs.SE and StackOverflow. Pick one to keep and delete the other. Thx.